# Set unix group permissions to my files and directories output from my perl script?

Tags: perl, unix

My script that i have works just how I want it to, with one exception. I would like to be able to automatically set the unix group permissions to the directory and files that I create in my perl script.

Is this possible, or do i just have to resort to

```
chgrp <group> <directory>
```

after running my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Perl's `chown` function as such:

```
# Get the GID as a number 
my $gid = getgrnam("group");

# Change the ownership 
chown -1, $gid, $dir; # Or $file or @list_of_files depending on your need
```

You may need privileges to do this however, as stated in the docs.
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chown.html